# How can I get a description of an added file in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

For a command "p4 changes CLnumber#" I get something like this:

"...

Affected files

...

Differences

..."

It doesn't show description of added files. I would also like to get full description of files added in a given CL. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "full description of files" ? Do you mean a list of the file names? Or something else? And, is the command that you are running really `p4 changes`? Or is it possibly `p4 describe`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want to display an added file.


"p4 changes" lists changelogs for a given user. "p4 describe" doesn't display file added in a changelog, it only shows differences between modified files.

I guess "p4 print" may be useful, but I don't know how can I use it knowing only number of changelist in which added files appear.

Comment: `p4 describe -s` definitely should *list* added (and removed) files.  Note that `p4 describe` won't print *diffs* for added/removed files, however.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is `p4 describe -du 1234` (where "1234" is the number of your changelist).

Comment: This won't print diffs for added (or removed) files.

Comment: ...because added or removed files won't have diffs. It will, though, tell you the file was added or deleted (or moved).